# Access violation when "resizing" array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, access-violation

So I'm trying to create a function that "resizes" a member array to a new size passed as an argument. By "resize", I mean that it should set the member array to a new array with the new size, copy over the elements from the old array, and then deallocate the memory associated with the old array. Here's what I have so far:

```
void MemoryTest::resize(unsigned int new_size) {
    if (size == new_size)
        return;

    int* oldPtr = elements;

    elements = new int[new_size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < (new_size < size) ? new_size : size; i++)
        elements[i] = oldPtr[i];

    elements[new_size] = '\0';

    if (size > new_size)
        size = new_size;

    delete[] oldPtr; // Deallocate old elements array
}
```

elements is a private member int* initialized to NULL.

However, when it begins the for loop, the program hangs for awhile before giving an Access Violation for the elements[i] = oldPtr[i] line. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong (which I probably am), but my understanding is that oldPtr should be a pointer pointing to the same initial point as elements. Then, I set elements equal to a new array, so the two are now pointing to two different things. Then I iterate through elements, setting each item equal to its counterpart in the old array.

Also, while I would normally use a vector to avoid situations like this, I'm trying to become more familiar with pointers and memory allocation in C++.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your member variable `size` is not accurate after the first call to this function.  I can't determine if it's accurate *before*.

Comment: And now that you've changed the code, your member variable `size` will be wrong when the array is made larger.

Comment: I'm trying to make size reflect the number of elements, not the number of memory spots in the array, so it should only increase when new elements are added. That being said, the problem did lie in size, which was causing a problem with iterating through the for loop.

Comment: @user2884505 - `I'm trying to make size reflect the number of elements, not the number of memory spots in the array,` That's why vector has both `size` and `capacity` members.

Comment: I guess another reason to just use vectors haha. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for (int i = 0; i < (new_size < size) ? new_size : size; i++)`

should read

`for (int i = 0; (i < (new_size < size)) ? new_size : size; i++)`

So, `for (int i = 0; i < ((new_size < size) ? new_size : size); i++)` should correct your code.

Comment: Why not just a simple `for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that may be too many iterations for the new array.

Comment: @DrewDormann - Of course, I'm assuming that `size` remains the same until after all of the dynamic memory shenanigans is completed, and at the end of the function, `size` is set correctly to the new size.

Comment: Thank you, this did it! I have to wait two minutes to accept this answer, but this was one of the smallest wait times I've had lol. I really appreciate it everyone!